# How to configure Selenium Chromedriver to launch Chrome on specific virtual desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Chromedriver on Windows (in a C# CLI application, but *hopefully* this is irrelevant).

I would like to tell Selenium to launch Chrome on a specific virtual desktop. I do know how to launch a process on a specific virtual desktop, the issue is that in this case it is not me who launches the `chromedriver.exe` then subsequently `chrome.exe`.

Headless mode does not play in my case, because some tests run incorrectly in headless mode, but that is another issue.

How to configure Selenium to launch Chrome on a specific virtual desktop (and not on the current desktop)?